# mysql query not using the index i want

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following query left joining 2 tables :

```
explain 

    select 
        n.* from npi n left join npi_taxonomy nt on n.NPI=nt.NPI_CODE 

    where 
        n.Provider_First_Name like '%s%' and 
        n.Provider_Last_Name like '%b%' and 
        n.Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_State_Name = 'SC' and 
        n.Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_City_Name = 'charleston' and 
        n.Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code in (29001,29003,29010,29016,29018,29020,29030,29032,29033,29038,29039,29040,29041,29042,29044,29045,29046,29047,29048,29051,29052,29053,29056,29059,29061,29062,29069,29071,29072,29073,29078,29079,29080,29081,29082,29102,29104,29107,29111,29112,29113,29114,29115,29116,29117,29118,29123,29125,29128,29133,29135,29137,29142,29143,29146,29147,29148,29150,29151,29152,29153,29154,29160,29161,29162,29163,29164,29168,29169,29170,29171,29172,29201,29202,29203,29204,29205,29206,29207,29208,29209,29210,29212,29214,29215,29216,29217,29218,29219,29220,29221,29222,29223,29224,29225,29226,29227,29228,29229,29230,29240,29250,29260,29290,29292,29401,29402,29403,29404,29405,29406,29407,29409) and 
        n.Entity_Type_Code = 1 and 
        nt.Healthcare_Provider_Taxonomy_Code in ('101Y00000X') 

    limit 0,10;
```

I have added a multi-column index :

**npi_fname_lname_state_city_zip_entity** on the table npi which indexes the columns in the following order :

```
NPI,  
Provider_First_Name, 
Provider_First_Name, 
Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_State_Name, Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_City_Name, Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code, 
Entity_Type_Code
```

However, when i do an explain on the query, it shows me that it uses the primary index (NPI). Also, it says rows examined = 1

What's worse is : the query takes roughly **120** seconds to execute. How do i optimize this ?

I would really appreciate some help regarding this.

Comment: More on [_constructing indexes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and [_pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your multi column index doesn't help, is because you are filtering with a wild card `like '%s%'`.

Indexes can only be used when filtering using the **left most prefix** of the index, which means that 1) [cannot do a contains search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html), and 2) if the left most column of the multi column index cannot be used, the other columns in the index [cannot be used aswell](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

You should switch the order of the columns in the index to

```
Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_State_Name, 
Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_City_Name, 
Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code, 
Entity_Type_Code
```

That way MySql will only scan the rows that match those the criteria for those columns (SC, charleston etc).

Alternatively, look into [full text indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).